# Can't display text in a simple javafx application

Tags: java, javafx

I'm struggling to display text in a simple javafx application, and I'm struggling to see why it's happening. Here's my code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    //Declarations
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 960, 600);
    javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas background = new Canvas(3840, 2160);

    StackPane infoPane = new StackPane();
    Text test = new Text("Hello");
    test.setY(500);
    test.setX(500);
    root.getChildren().add(test);

    //Stage Setting
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Test application");
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.setFullScreenExitHint("Press escape to exit fullscreen");
    primaryStage.show();
    //javafx.scene.image.Image icon = new Image("Sample/Test.png");
    //primaryStage.getIcons().add(icon);

    //Parent and child declarations
    infoPane.getChildren().add(test);

    //Styling

    //Background
    StackPane backgroundHolder = new StackPane();
    backgroundHolder.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #0053A8");
    backgroundHolder.getChildren().add(background);
    root.getChildren().add(backgroundHolder);
}
```

The idea is to have an application with a blue background, that has different text fields on it. Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the `test` node to your `root` Pane, but then you add it also to `infoPane`. Since a node can only appear once in the scene graph, you are essentially removing it from the root pane before you can see it.

Note that you never add `infoPane` to your scene graph.

I suggest you read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102), and maybe try a few simple layouts with [Scene Builder](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/).

Comment: Ah, so it was just messy coding. Thanks a lot! I was really struggling for quite a while.